# Does an audio file become smaller in size when it is Base64 encoded?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base64

Just wondering, as I was considering storing audio files into a database this way.

Comment: It becomes larger, by a factor of, on average, [4/3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage).

Comment: encodings generally *increase* the size of the data.

Comment: what's with the downvotes? I don't see any signs of a bad question personally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[base64 wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Base64 encoded will be about 1.37 times larger than binary.