# DES encryption plain vs. cipher length

Tags: java, encryption, des, encryption-symmetric

I am using Java to make a toy program that encrypts a message using DES encryption. The message I want to encrypt is:

```
String msg="This is a secret message";
```

Which I convert to bytes as:

```
byte [] msgBytes=msg.getBytes();
```

And send it to encrypt function that works as follows:

```
//encryption function
public static String encryptMsg(byte [] msgBytes, SecretKey myDesKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Cipher desCipher;
    // Create the cipher 
    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(msgBytes);

// converts to base64 for easier display.
byte[] base64Cipher = Base64.encode(textEncrypted);
return new String(base64Cipher);
} //end encryptMsg
```

Then, I display the cipher, the cipher and plaintext lengths and I get:

```
Encrypted Message: FDCU+kgWz25urbQB5HbFtqm0HqWHGlGBHlwwEatFTiI=
Original msg length: 24
Encrypted msg length: 44
```

Can you please clarify to me why the cipher length is 44 while the original message length is 24?

**EDIT:**
Kindly, I need the answer with clarification. The cipher always ends with =. Could this be because of the padding? Can you explain to me why/how the cipher is resulted with this length? And always ends with =? 
Is my code correct or there is a mistake? I have doubts in the encoding part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on:

1. [`msg.getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) returns the bytes representing an encoding of the string using the "platform's default charset" (e.g. could be UTF-8 *or* UTF-16 *or* ..): [specify the encoding manually](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) to avoid confusion! In any case, see `msgBytes.length` to get the *true* plain text length.
2. [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES), being a block cypher, will have output padded along a [block size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_(cryptography)) boundary - *but* this will *always* be larger than the plain text (refer to `msgBytes.length`) length when using [PKCS#5](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) because the plain text is always padded with [1,8] bytes. To see what the *true* encrypted size is, see `textEncrypted.length`.
3. The encrypted bytes are encoded using base-64 and this process - which is independent of the encryption - inflates the number of bytes required [by about 33%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage) (as only 6 bits per character/byte are used). The Java base-64 implementation also [adds padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) which is where the trailing "=" character is introduced.

As long as you (or someone else with the correct algorithm and cipher key) can retrieve the initial string - by performing the inverse of each step in reverse order, then it works. If a particular step does not have an inverse/reverse operation or cannot be "undone", then something is wrong; but this also means that *every step can be individually tested*.

---

To the numbers!

1. `msg.getBytes()` returns an ASCII/UTF-8 encoded sequence (if it used UTF-16 or another another "wide" encoding then the numbers below would be too large)
2. Therefore, `msgBytes.length` is 24
3. And since `msgBytes.length` mod 8 is 0, the plain text is *padded* with 8 bytes that have the value of 0x08 (per CKCS#5)
4. Thus, `textEncrypted.length` is 32 (24 data + 8 padding)
5. Due to base-64 encoding, 32 bytes * 1.33 ~ 43 characters
6. And with base-64 padding (`=`), the final result is 44 characters!

Answer (score 2):

The result of a DES encryption will always be a multiple of 8 bytes. The input is also padded to a multiple of 8 bytes according to the padding algorithm specified.

The base 64 encoding encodes each 3 bytes into 4 characters (3x8 = 4x6 = 24), and ensures the output length is a multiple of 4 by padding with = characters.

So, the 44 characters output corresponds to 33 bytes, but the = at the end indicates that in fact there were only 32 bytes. Which is fine, since 24 bytes clear data with PKCS5 padding becomes 32 bytes.