# When and why decorate OutputStream with ArmoredOutputStream when using BouncyCastle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

I'm pretty new to BouncyCastle and pgp. I've seen many articles and samples on the internet. Almost every encryption sample contains the code snipped below

```
if (armor) 
        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
```

It seems that my local test passed with both armor and none-armor. I googled around but found few useful and the javadoc of ArmoredOutputStream only shows This is basic output stream.

So what's the difference and when to use it?

Complete code sample:

```
public static void encryptFile(String decryptedFilePath,
        String encryptedFilePath,
        String encKeyPath,
        boolean armor,
        boolean withIntegrityCheck)            
        throws Exception{

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFilePath);
    FileInputStream pubKey = new FileInputStream(encKeyPath);
    PGPPublicKey encKey = readPublicKeyFromCollection2(pubKey);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    if (armor) 
        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);

    // Init encrypted data generator
    PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator =
            new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom(),"BC");

    encryptedDataGenerator.addMethod(encKey);


    OutputStream encryptedOut = encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]);

    // Init compression  
    PGPCompressedDataGenerator compressedDataGenerator = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZIP);
    OutputStream compressedOut = compressedDataGenerator.open(encryptedOut);  

    PGPLiteralDataGenerator literalDataGenerator = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
    OutputStream literalOut = literalDataGenerator.open(compressedOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, decryptedFilePath, new Date(), new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]);
    FileInputStream inputFileStream = new FileInputStream(decryptedFilePath);
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];  
    int len;
    while((len = inputFileStream.read(buf))>0){
        literalOut.write(buf,0,len);
    }

    literalOut.close();
    literalDataGenerator.close();

    compressedOut.close();
    compressedDataGenerator.close();
    encryptedOut.close();
    encryptedDataGenerator.close();
    inputFileStream.close();
    out.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ArmoredOutputStream`  uses an encoding similar to [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), so that binary non-printable bytes are converted to something text friendly. You'd do this if you wanted to send the data over email, or post on a site, or some other text medium.

It doesn't make a difference in terms of security. There is [a slight expansion of the message size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage) though. The choice really just depends on what you want to do with the output.

Answer (score 7):

ASCII armor is a generic term that means a binary data representation as an ASCII-only text. Technically, there is a lot of ways to [ascii-armor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_armor) binary data, but in the cryptography-related field [the PEM format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421) is prevalent (also check [this and related questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file) at serverfault).

The PEM is basically a Base64-encoded binary data wrapped in `-----BEGIN SOMETHING-----` and `-----END SOMETHING-----` delimiters and a set of additional headers that can contain some meta information about the binary content.