# hash_hmac() returning a 30 character signature, not a 32 character signature

Tags: php, oauth, hmacsha1

Expecting these series of functions to produce a 32 character long signature for authenticating via OAuth v1.

```
    $h = hash_hmac("sha1", $url, $key, $raw_output=TRUE);
    $signature = base64_encode($h);
```

However it's consistently producing a 30 character long signature even when I change the $url parameters. Am I understanding how to create OAuth signatures?

Answer (score 0):

sha1 produces 20 bytes. Since base64 will increase the string length [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715480/505722) this will produce a string 28 characters long (this may be longer if you call `urlencode` on the signature).

I'm not as familiar with oauth but there doesn't seem to be anything in the spec which mandates a 32 character signature.