# Is it necessary to have base64_encode

Tags: php, base64, imgur

I'm using the [following tutorial](http://subinsb.com/uploading-images-using-imgur-api-in-php) to upload an image to imgur. I want to know whether it's necessary to have `base64_encode` when sending the data.

Here's a small code snippet:

```
$img=$_FILES['img'];
$filename = $img['tmp_name'];
$data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($data)); // Here's the base64_encode
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
```

Is it necessary to have `base64_encode` and why?

To see the full code, you can go [here](http://subinsb.com/uploading-images-using-imgur-api-in-php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is base 64 encoding used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Imgur](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image) documentation, there are alternative methods.

[image]

So, to answer your question, no it is not *required* as long as it is one of the other two supported options.

Comment: Another important note is base64 encoding something increases the size by 4/3, so binary should be preferred if possible, especially if the 10MB limit is on the base64 encoded string.

Comment: Which one is recommended?

Comment: Oh... Thanks! So I can just replace `$pvars` with `$data`?

Comment: I don't think cURL will do it like that directly, take a look at this: http://ryansechrest.com/2012/07/send-and-receive-binary-files-using-php-and-curl/. Out of curiosity, what is the opposition to base64? Is the file to big?

Comment: @cillosis 2 things. 1st:  I will be passing either an image or a url. I don't think I can do base64 to a url. 2nd: The user will be able to upload a larger file. Which leads to another question. If I do base64, then how can I know how many megabits to limit the user?

Comment: Well, you can give a URL no problem to imgur according to their docs. As for calculating the size of base64 encoded, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage

Comment: Right, but I don't think I can give a base64 URL.

Comment: Right. That's an option. So are you suggesting I use base64?

Comment: I'm suggesting it would be *easier*. Feel free to play with cURL and see if you can get the binary post to go through as that would increase the maximum file size you can support, but it can be tricky is all I am saying.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Feel free not to answer the next question because it ins't in the scope of the original question. I'm trying to figure out the maximum file size for anonymous uploads (for GIFs and other formats (like (jpg)). The image in your answer says it's 10 mb. But in https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201476437-What-is-the-maximum-file-size-for-uploads- it says 1mb for regular images, and 200mb for GIFs. Which one is it? (I'm using anonymous uploads only.)

Comment: My answer was for the API which, I assume, means you need an account. The article you linked to might be more accurate for anonymous uploads. As always, give it a try and see ;-)

Comment: 1 more question. If it works with a couple of uploads without base64, does that mean it will always work?

Comment: This is IT, it will never *always* work! Heh. Be sure to check the return value of curl for false and handle the error available using `curl_error($curl)` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

No it´s not necessary, and I don't know if this is a common practice for posting huge images.

You can also use the cURL option `CURLOPT_INFILE`

**BEWARE:** The below examples, may not work, they are just untestet examples.

```
// This is the entire file that was uploaded to a temp location.
$localFile = $_FILES[$fileKey]['tmp_name']; 

$fp = fopen($localFile, 'r');

// Connecting to website.
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localFile));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

**Or just a simple POST**

```
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```