# Size of binary file after base64 encoding? Need explanation on the solution

Tags: encoding, binary, base64, size, ascii

So I'm studying for the upcoming exam, and there's this question: given a binary file with the size of 31 bytes what will its size be, after encoding it to base64?

The solution teacher gave us was (40 + 4) bytes as it needs to be a multiple of 4.

I'm not being able to come across this solution, and I have no idea how to solve this, so I was hoping somebody could help me figure this out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because base 64 encoding divide the input data in six bit block and one block use an ascii code. 
If you have 31 byte in input you have 31*8/6 bit block to encode. As a rule of thumb every three byte in input you have 4 byte in output
If input data is not  a multiple of six bit the base64 encoding fills the last block with 0 bit 
In your example you have 42 block of six bit, with last filled with missing 0 bit.
Base 64 algorithm implementation filled the encoded data with '=' symbol in order to have of multiple of 4 as final result.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but doing your math: 31*8/6 = 41.333.. How do I end up with the 44? I'm sorry my question sounds dumb.

Comment: I add some explanation