# Kubernetes Secrets vs ConfigMaps

Tags: kubernetes

Have been using Kubernetes secrets up to date.
Now we have ConfigMaps as well.

What is the preferred way forward - secrets or config maps?

P.S. After a few iterations we have stabilised at the following rule:

- configMaps are per solution domain (can be shared across microservices within the domain, but ultimately are single purpose config entries)
- secrets are shared across solution domains, usually represent third party systems or databases

Answer (score 185, accepted):

I'm the author of both of these features. The idea is that you should:

1. Use [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) for things which are actually secret like API keys, credentials, etc
2. Use [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) for not-secret configuration data

In the future, there will likely be some differentiators for secrets like rotation or support for backing the secret API w/ HSMs, etc.  In general, we like intent-based APIs, and the intent is definitely different for secret data vs. plain old configs.

Comment: A hopefully clarifying question. For it seems like secrets are still stored as plain text (base64), so the naming might be a little bit misleading at the moment if you ask me since. Or could you elaborate around that? I do agree, that intention based API is the way to go.

Comment: Is it possible to use a secret inside of a config map?  It is quite common that an application config file contains both secret, and non-secret data.  For example, the tomcat server.xml contains both port numbers (non-secret) and shutdown password (secret)...  It would be nice to represent that as a single resource...

Comment: Should each connection string be its own Secret, or should I have something like a "ConnectionStrings" secret that contains all of them?

Comment: @sg it depends on what works best for you.  My recommendation would be to group information into secrets that reflects how you manage that information.  IE, two different systems managed separately probably ought to be in separate secrets.  A single bag of all the creds an app uses that you manage as a single unit is probably fine to go into a single secret.  Hope that answer helps.

Comment: @Lucas no, that's not possible with the bare primitives.  A mechanism like the one you asked for is certainly valid, but it should be at a higher level than configmaps and secrets.  You may be interested in this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2196

Comment: @TomasJansson secrets now support encryption at rest: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/

Comment: @PaulMorie, I ended up writing a [utility that merge's yamls](https://gitlab.com/pastdev/s2i/tree/master/clconf) to accomodate my needs.  So we supply our containers with a ConfigMap yaml with all the non secret values, and a Secret yaml with the secret values, then use this to merge them and present as a single config.  Works great by itself or with other tools (like [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd))...

Comment: That's really cool @Lucas, I think a lot of folks would be interested in that. You should show that at sig-apps sometime!

Comment: @PaulMorie what is sig-apps?

Comment: @Lucas see https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/08/sig-apps-running-apps-in-kubernetes

Comment: Can you please explain the current (1.10) implementation difference between a Secret and a ConfigMap (regardless of intent)? Other than Base64 encoding and encryption at rest.

Comment: Link to @Lucas Utility mentioned above - https://github.com/pastdev/clconf.

Comment: Thanks @slm, looks like it was too late for me to edit the original comment...  Had to move it to github to attempt to get it merged into `confd`, but they went a different direction.  I still actively use a `clconf` in all my container projects with a custom fork of confd: github.com/pastdev/confd.

Comment: @Lucas - thanks, just stumbled onto your `clconf` tool yday, was planning to try to work it into some of our deployment scenarios as well.

Comment: @PaulMorie are secret update and configmap update atomic operations? I asked a question here. What is the flow when a client updates secret or configmap? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529204/are-kubernetes-api-calls-secret-update-and-configmap-update-atomic-calls

Comment: If  a  config  file  includes  both  sensitive  and  not-sensitive  data,  you should store the file in a Secret

Comment: @PaulMorie It's been a couple years since this answer. Has there been any development? Are they still basically them same in terms om implementation?

Comment: I am not sure that it's possible: typical scenario is "I use some 3rd party tool, it has a config file, config file may (or not) content password/token". It means that no any difference between plain config file and "secret" config file. Do you plan to substitute secrets in the plain config files?! Surprise, but there are even binary config files lol. If you don't plan to do it, then what is the difference for me, the end user?

Comment: Another question is: if I use always secrets instead of config maps - what can be drawbacks/problems of such approach?

Comment: Another drawback of secret is that base64 encoded data grows... see this answer to know more about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715480/1564365. Basically you can pack more configuration data in configmap (up to 1mb because of the etcd limit), you won't be able to pack the same amount in secret (same limit 1mb)... and I've been burned by the limit before (hi Rancher).

Comment: @Kyslik compress the secret before base64.

Comment: How we can get expected security by using base64? base64 can be decoded easily.

Comment: @srimaln91You don't really get security with Secrets

Comment: I think it would be better to use WorkloadIdentity if your cloud provider supports it, https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/workload-identity-secrets#create-secret.

Answer (score 11):

One notable difference in the implementation is that `kubectl apply -f`:

- ConfigMaps are "unchanged" if the data hasn't changed.
- Secrets are always "configured" - even if the file hasn't changed

Comment: Oooh! Nice gotcha.

Answer (score -2):

**Kubernetes secrets** are used to store information in encrypted form . So that even if is any unauthorised access is made the attacker is not able to do anything as he needs decryption key . They are used to store sensitive information.

**Kubernetes Config Maps** are used store non confidential info in key value store . Pods may use them cli, env variables.

Comment: "secrets are used to store information in encrypted form" <- This is wrong, they are _encoded_ but *not* encrypted

Answer (score -8):

Both, ConfigMaps and Secrets store data as a key value pair. The major difference is, **Secrets store data in base64** format meanwhile **ConfigMaps store data in a plain text**.

If you have some secret data like, API secrets, sa accounts, etc then you should always go for **Secrets** rather than Configs.

And if you want to do some application configuration using environment variables which you don't want to keep secret/hidden like, app theme, base platform url, etc then you can go for **ConfigMaps**

Comment: how base64 protects the secrets? it is just foolproof, not protection.

Comment: base64 is no protection at all.

Comment: ConfigMaps can also store base64 encoded data if you use the `binaryData` field instead of `data`.

Comment: Likewise you can store text-based secrets with `stringData` instead of `data`. Makes it easier to edit, actually.

Comment: Correct advice for the wrong reason.

Comment: lol @Jimbali so they are both kind of redundant, when dealing with really sensitive data like client ID, client secret etc. values