# How to handle incomplete provided secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

## Background

I'm currently developing a Helm Chart for my application. The chart has a dependency to [`bitnami/mongodb`](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mongodb). That chart creates the following secret:

```yaml
---
# Source: mongodb/templates/secrets.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: RELEASENAME-mongodb
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb
    helm.sh/chart: mongodb-8.2.1
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASENAME
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: mongodb
type: Opaque
data:
  mongodb-root-password:  "ZHVtbXlwYXNzd29yZA=="
  mongodb-password:  "cGFzc3dvcmQ="
```

(`helm template RELEASENAME bitnami/mongodb --set auth.rootPassword=dummypassword,auth.username=username,auth.password=password,auth.database=database`)

My application of course wants to make use of the provided MongoDB, however I need to provide more than just the password but also a username, database and a connection URI to it in order to be able to connect to the database.

## Question

What's the best way to provide the entire configuration (username, password, database, connection URI) to my application container without duplicating the existing secret and also without distributing the configuration among multiple configuration sources (configmap, secret, environment) ?

**Edit (concretization):**
Since this question revolves around Helm Chart development, I'd like to have a self contained solution within my Chart instead of having to rely on patching / updating the deployment objects in the cluster once `helm install` has run.

## Thoughts / Remarks

Probably the simplest way is to provide everything via the environment. However the list will get longer and longer the more dependencies get added to my application. I've noticed that people seem to prefer config maps / secrets over plain environment configuration.

**However** I can't find a way to reference one secret from another secret in such a way as it is possible in the environment config via an [EnvVarSource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#envvarsource-v1-core).

Next I thought about patching the existing secret to add the missing credentials somehow while the chart is still rendering, however I can't find a way to do that.

Finally I could provide the username, database and connection URI via a second secret or a config map (depending on whether you would consider those part of the credentials [[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36925553/966530)]) and only provide the password via the environment. What I don't like about this approach is that I'd have to split up one logical configuration unit into multiple sources.

Comment: So you want to add new values in already deployed secret? If so you can achieve it using `kubectl patch`

Comment: I don't neccesarily *want* to add new values, I'm rather asking for the best practises when it comes to Helm Chart development. Furthermore `kubectl patch` would have to be another operation after the `helm install`. (Unless I'm missing something?) I'd like to have a self-contained solution that handles everything inside the helm template rendering process.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the imprecision in my question tho. I've updated it to be more specific.