# Why aren't the uploaded image stored in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store image on my mysql database. I know that it may not be the smartest thing to do, but this job requires it. I have looked online on how to store an image using php code, however every time I try to follow the guidelines it seems like a random problem pops up. With this code am using right now, I've managed to get all the information stored in the database except the image and the image name. Any suggestions on how to make it work?

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "dbname");  
 if(!empty($_POST))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["title"]);  
      $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
      $image = file_get_contents($image);
      $image = base64_encode($image);
      $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["text2"]);  
      $text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["text1"]);       
      $dtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
      $query = "  
      INSERT INTO news(title, image, name, text2, text1, dtime)  
      VALUES('$title', '{$image}', '$name', '$text2', '$text1', '$dtime');  
      ";
```

I have tried different options, adding $connect into $image and $name to make it like the rest or changing addslashes into mysql_real_escape_string.

I need some help to get it to work,if you have the time I'll appreciate it!

Comment: Do u have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form? you don't want to upload it to folder?

Comment: What is your image column data type?

Comment: show us your form too

Comment: Yes thats the thing.. I do have it but still.. it wouldn't work

Comment: <form method="post" id="insert_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<label>Bild</label>  
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control" />
<input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Spara" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>

Comment: can u please show us your form?

Comment: This is the form (besides the rest of the input tags).. I can't show you it online because it is stored behind a member access page.

Comment: can you please 'echo' $name?did you get any value?

Comment: I have looked into my phpmyadmin and there are no values either in image (longblob) row or name (varchar) row...

Comment: did you print ($_FILES)?

Comment: no I didn't.. but thank you for the help! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are adding slashes to the file path before reading the file.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "dbname");  
 if(!empty($_POST))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["title"]);

      // Replace below two lines...
      //   $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      //   $image = file_get_contents($image);
      // With:
      $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
      $image = base64_encode($image);
      $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["text2"]);  
      $text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["text1"]);       
      $dtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
      $query = "  
      INSERT INTO news(title, image, name, text2, text1, dtime)  
      VALUES('$title', '{$image}', '$name', '$text2', '$text1', '$dtime');  
      ";
```

Also you probably don't want to store a base64_encoded file in your database as it increases storage size ([Base64: What is the worst possible increase in space usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage)). Store the image as a blob (= binary data) in your database.

Considering this didn't work for you, try the following to debug:

```
<?php
// Print out the submitted files and the data.
var_dump($_FILES);
// Check to see if it's not empty, whether the submitted filename is actually "image", 


echo (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ? 'File exists!' : 'File does not exist'), PHP_EOL;

echo (is_readable($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ? 'Can read the file!' : 'Can not read the file'), PHP_EOL;

$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

echo 'File size: ', strlen($file), ' bytes (base64: ', strlen(base64_encode($file)), ' bytes)';
```

Try that and see if anything is out of the ordinary...

Comment: @MattiasMatte see my edit, maybe it can help you figure out the source of the problem

Comment: Thank you for the help. I managed to solve it. I think the problem was maybe me using ajax,when Iremoved it the files got uploaded! ;D