# DynamoDB larger than 400KB items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, large-data

I am planning to create a merchant table, which will have store locations of the merchant. Most merchants are small businesses and they only have a few stores. However, there is the odd multi-chain/franchise who may have hundreds of locations.

What would be my solution if I want to put include location attributes within the merchant table? If I have to split it into multiple tables, how do I achieve that?

Thank you!

EDIT: How about splitting the table. To cater for the majority, say up to 5 locations I can place them inside the same table. But beyond 5, it will spill over to a normalised table with an indicator on the main table to say there are more than 5 locations. Any thoughts on how to achieve that?

Comment: It might be worth looking up some dynamodb talks that cover how to denormalize your data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of options depending on your access patterns:

- Compress the data and store the binary object in DynamoDB.
- Store basic details in DynamoDB along with a link to S3 for the larger things. There's no transactional support across DynamoDB and S3 so there's a chance your data could become inconsistent.
- Rather than embed location attributes, you could normalise your tables and put that data in a separate table with the equivalent of a foreign key to your merchant table. But, you may then need two queries to retrieve data for each merchant, which would count towards your throughput costs.
- Catering for a spill-over table would have to be handled in the application code rather than at the database level: `if (store_count > 5) then execute another query to retrieve more data`

If you don't need the performance and scalability of DynamoDB, perhaps RDS is a better solution.

Comment: I'd like to explore binary compressions. Does DynamoDB query/write automatically decode/encode to text? what is the performance degradation? According to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html, it uses Base64. I am not well versed, but how much storage savings will I get?

Whilst on this subject, will this be a good way to store email/chat messages in binary format?

Comment: By the way, can you add a secondary index on binary type attributes?

Comment: The GZIP and LZO compression algorithms produce a binary output suitable for a storing as a binary object. You might need to experiment with each algorithm to see which is best for your data. Check out 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html, which has more details and a complete example for Java and matches pretty closely your email/chat use case.

Comment: Scalar data types (Number, String, Binary, and Boolean) can be used for the sort key element of a local secondary index.

Comment: Thanks craigcaulfield. Just looking at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage it appears encoding it into binary increases the size 4/3 of the original size. Why would people call this process compression?

Comment: That link refers to base64. You'll likely get better compression with one of the other algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I believe the right schema would be to have `partitionKey` as merchantId with `sortKey` as storeId. This would create individual, separate records for each store and you can store the geo location. This way

- You would not cross the 400KB threshold
- Queries become efficient if you want to fetch the location for just 1 of the stores of the merchant. If you want to fetch all the stores, there is no impact with this schema.

PS : I am a Software Engineer working on Amazon Dynamodb.