# Send Mail with mixed sized attachments (> 4MB) using Graph API (version 2.3.2)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I've following list of attachments to send in mail

- 210KBPDF.pdf
- 1MBPDF.pdf
- 4MBPDF.pdf

To send total file size under 4 MB(1MBPDF, 210KBPDF) I can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664240/send-mail-with-multiple-attachments-size-4-mb-using-graph-api-version-2-3-2/64664837#64664837) approach and
To send large file (4MBPDF) I'm using solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262929/email-with-multiple-attachments-using-graph-api-4-mb)

But when I'm trying to send three files (1MBPDF, 210KBPDF, 4MBPDF) together using large file approach ([Sample code](https://github.com/vivekbdh/GraphMailAttachment/blob/master/src/main/java/MixedFileUploadExample.java)) I'm getting following error...

> com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code:
> ErrorAttachmentSizeShouldNotBeLessThanMinimumSize Error message:
> Attachment size must be greater than the minimum size.
>
> POST
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkAGNhNWJlNjdkLWNkZTUtNDE1Yy1hYzkxLTkyOWI1M2U3NGQzOABGAAAAAAASIVxVSsS8RI-T3F73mdJZBwANqxyKMlQbSqZO439E21_mAAAAAAEPAAANqxyKMlQbSqZO439E21_mAAAVRY2dAAA=/attachments/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession
> SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.2 Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
> {"attachmentItem":{"attachmentType":"file","conten[...]
>
> 400 : Bad Request [...]

Please let me know if I'm making any mistakes to implement the approach or suggest me any work-around to send multiple attachments mixed in size.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Vivek , if you have done it can you share the code for the community please.  It will help me as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the approach I suggest you take to avoid any issues:

1. Create a [draft email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. Upload any attachment <3MB via the [add attachment endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
3. Upload any attachment >3MB via the [large upload endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http)
4. Send the [email endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

With that approach instead of trying to upload the small attachments with the draft email creation, you'll avoid random failures when the total size of base64 encoded small attachments exceeds the maximum size of 4MB per request on Microsoft Graph.

Comment: This was the best advice I could find on this matter.  To save you some major headaches give this a shot for the large upload endpoint session - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp

Comment: Hi baywet, I went to each of the link yo provided,  all the links are evenly sending the email at the end.  I am able to send multiple emails but in smaller sizes.  And a single large file.  When I see your solution, each of link sending email at the end.  When I put them together , they all look seperate task.  How I can combine them all together.