# Microsoft Graph API using uploadsession not able to recieve email with attachments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Email Not been recieved with attachments when I try to use Uploadsession using Graph API. can someone help me uderstand why this is happening. I have not recieved any error.

```
      Message draft = await graphServiceClient.Users["UserID"].Messages.Request().AddAsync(email);
        //Message draft = graphServiceClient.Users["UserID"].Mailfolders.Drafts.Messages.Request().AddAsync(email);

        var stream = System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\attach\DYN28_6579332_33242556.csv", System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        var attachmentItem = new AttachmentItem
        {
            AttachmentType = AttachmentType.File,
            Name = "DYN28_6579332_33242556.csv",
            Size = stream.Length
        };
        var uploadSession = await graphServiceClient.Users["Userid"].Messages[draft.Id]
                                .Attachments
                                .CreateUploadSession(attachmentItem)
                                .Request()
                                .PostAsync();
        var maxSlicesize = 320 * 1024;
        var largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<FileAttachment>(uploadSession, stream, maxSlicesize);
        IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog => {
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {stream.Length} bytes");
        });

            // Upload the file
            var uploadResult = await largeFileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

            if (uploadResult.UploadSucceeded)
            {
            // The ItemResponse object in the result represents the
            // created item.
            //Console.WriteLine($"Upload complete, item ID: {uploadResult.ItemResponse.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine("upload completed");
            }

  Finally sending email with 
                                                                      
                                                                         
  await graphServiceClient.Users["userid"].Messages[draft.Id]
                                  .Send()
                                  .Request()
                                  .PostAsync();
```

Comment: They have a limit of ~3MB use S3 download link if you have it.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use SMTP for sending the mail, which doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: Or send it as a ZIP

Comment: We have recently migrated to graph API..earlier we used to have SMTP which doesn't have any restrictions.What is S3 download link?

Comment: Can you please give me code on how to zip the attachments and send it through email using graph API

Comment: Use any package of your choice recommendation is https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 4MB on a single request in the Graph API. To send larger attachments, you need to first create an upload session against the email message/calendar event, and upload your attachment in a number of requests as part of this session. AFAIK each of the smaller POST requests would also need to stay below the 4MB limit.

You can find more detailed documentation and a sample walkthrough [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=/attachments/createUploadSession
Content-type: application/json

{
  "AttachmentItem": {
    "attachmentType": "file",
    "name": "flower",
    "size": 3483322
  }
}
```

Comment: Smaller attachements should be less than 3MB? In our scenario we have customer data where sometimes the attachments is more than 15MB..In this case it will fail along.Do we have any other option where I can send all the attachments in single mail.Or any version needs to be updated

Comment: An upload session is used to upload a file larger than 4MB to the server in parts. The attachment is yet sent as a single item within a single email message. It is only uploaded in parts to the server. The recipient will see it as a single file/item.

Comment: In case you want to attach multiple large files to an email message, you can create separate upload sessions for each of them. A single upload session is for uploading a large file in pieces to the server. You can create multiple sessions simultaneously. After you're done uploading the attachments, you can send the email.

Comment: I have tried with console application to send large attachments of size 16MB with email.I am able to get the size and upload session created, drafted the email but i have not recieved any email.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the error you are facing?

Comment: I am not getting any error. but the delivery failed to below recipients. And i have one more question as i have multiple attachments with different sizes to send through mail.How can I Achieve this?

Comment: There are two things here - uploading attachments and then sending the message. You first create a message, then upload all your attachments on this draft message. When you are done uploading all these, then send the email. So the API calls you make are: create message, create upload session, upload attachment parts, send message. You can repeat the attachment calls for all your attachments.

Comment: This same list of steps is also mentioned in this related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675294/send-mail-with-mixed-sized-attachments-4mb-using-graph-api-version-2-3-2?rq=1)