# How to effectivetly store tons of images in local database in flutter/android

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, offline

I have to create an application for a Doctor. Where the doctor can find the past records of all the prescriptions which were taken in the form of images (physical paper prescription captured by a mobile camera). I can call the api's to get them from a server when the network is available. But there is no way to save those huge amounts of images in a local storage and access them when there is no network.
I'm looking for a solution. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Answer (score 0):

On possible way to do it may be converting your images into base64 string and save it in your db.base64 string will have much lower weight about 30% if I am right.

Comment: This is incorrect. In fact it would inflate the size by ~33% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715415/base64-what-is-the-worst-possible-increase-in-space-usage